# Uploading an array of MultipartFile objects using Swagger-UI to the Spring Boot app?

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, multipartform-data, swagger-ui

I'm trying to upload array of `.pdf`/`.docx`/`.whatever`.

As per Swagger's [docs](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/describing-request-body/file-upload/) they do enable sending an array of files. I just don't know how to tell `Swagger-UI` to create that kind of request.

I have following dependencies for `Swagger` (not sure whether this refers to `OAS2` or `OAS3`):

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

Here is my `SwaggerConfig` class (placed within package of `main` Spring Boot function):

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig { 

    @Bean
    public Docket swaggerPlugin() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .select()
                .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
                .build()
                
                .securitySchemes(Arrays.asList(apiKey()))
                .securityContexts(Arrays.asList(securityContext()))
                .apiInfo(metaData());
    }

    private ApiInfo metaData() {
        return new ApiInfoBuilder()
                .title("Spring Boot REST API - Garbage Collectors App")
                .description("*")
                .version("1.0.0")
                .license("Apache License Version 2.0")
                .licenseUrl("http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0")
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityConfiguration security() {
        return SecurityConfigurationBuilder.builder().scopeSeparator(",")
                .additionalQueryStringParams(null)
                .useBasicAuthenticationWithAccessCodeGrant(false).build();
    }

    private ApiKey apiKey() {
        return new ApiKey("apiKey", "Authorization", "header");
    }

    private SecurityContext securityContext() {
        return SecurityContext.builder().securityReferences(defaultAuth())
                .forPaths(PathSelectors.any()).build();
    }

    private List<SecurityReference> defaultAuth() {
        AuthorizationScope authorizationScope = new AuthorizationScope(
                "global", "accessEverything");
        AuthorizationScope[] authorizationScopes = new AuthorizationScope[1];
        authorizationScopes[0] = authorizationScope;
        return Arrays.asList(new SecurityReference("apiKey",
                authorizationScopes));
    }

    @Bean
    UiConfiguration uiConfig() {
        return UiConfigurationBuilder.builder()
                .deepLinking(true)
                .displayOperationId(false)
                .defaultModelsExpandDepth(1)
                .defaultModelExpandDepth(1)
                .defaultModelRendering(ModelRendering.EXAMPLE)
                .displayRequestDuration(true)
                .docExpansion(DocExpansion.NONE)
                .filter(false)
                .maxDisplayedTags(null)
                .operationsSorter(OperationsSorter.ALPHA)
                .showExtensions(false)
                .tagsSorter(TagsSorter.ALPHA)
                .supportedSubmitMethods(UiConfiguration.Constants.DEFAULT_SUBMIT_METHODS)
                .validatorUrl(null)
                .build();
    }

}
```

Also, here is the controller I'm using:

```
@ApiParam(allowMultiple=true) 
@RequestMapping(value = "/send/email", consumes = {"multipart/form-data"}, method = RequestMethod.POST) 
    public String sendEmail(@RequestParam("attachments") MultipartFile[] attachments) throws IOException {
        
        System.out.println(attachments.length);
        
        return "test";
}
```

I'm able to pick an array of files from file system:

[image]

But after sending request I get following error:

```
{
      "timestamp": "2020-12-22T18:29:29.578+00:00",
      "status": 400,
      "error": "Bad Request",
      "trace": "org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MissingServletRequestPartException: Required request part 'attachments' is not present org.springframework.web.method.annotation.RequestParamMethodArgumentResolver.handleMissingValue(RequestParamMethodArgumentResolver.java:199)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.method.annotation.AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.resolveArgument(AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.java:114)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:121)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:170)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:106)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:894)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808)\r\n\tat
}
```

On the other hand single `MultipartFile` upload and any number of individually pre-determined MultipartFile can be uploaded without any problems.

What did I else tried:

-going over google inside and out
-reading the docs: In [here](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/4600) I can see that they made a fix on the issue but I still don't know how to tell Swagger-UI to make request which I'm specifying on server-side, no matter which dependency version I user.
-try to set `application.ymal` like so:

```
 requestBody:
    content:
      multipart/form-data:
        schema:
          type: object
          properties:
            orderId:
              type: integer
            userId:
              type: integer
            fileName:
              type: string
              format: binary
```

Also, I've tried these two dependencies:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
         <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    
    
    <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1</version>
        </dependency>   
    </dependencies>
```

My last solution is to allow sending up to 2-3 `MultipartFile`, but I would really like to avoid this. How can I configure this?

Comment: You need Springfox 3.0 or springdoc-openapi to upload arrays of files - these versions generate OpenAPI 3.0 definitions (where file arrays are supported) instead of OpenAPI 2.0. [Here's how the YAML should look like.](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/describing-request-body/file-upload/#multiple)

Comment: (cont.) I don't know the exact Java annotations that would generate this YAML, but maybe start with the multipart example [provided here](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/Swagger-2.X---Annotations#parameter), replace individual files with an array and use something like `@Parameter(array = @ArraySchema(type = "string", format = "binary"))`

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this in Swagger 2.x. As per Swagger doc.

> However, uploading an arbitrary number of files (an array of files) is not supported. There is an open feature request at https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues/254. For now, you can use a binary string array as a workaround for uploading an arbitrary number of files:

[Swagger 2 Documentation](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/2-0/file-upload/)